# Check if user is in a group of another site within multisite network

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite

I'm using Woocommerce + the groups plugin on my main site to promote users to a 'Premium' group upon purchasing items which works great.

If a user on the main site then browses to the second site within my network, I can no longer check to see if they're within the 'Premium' group.

On my main site, I can use this code:

```
<?php 
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $group = Groups_Group::read_by_name( 'Premium' );
    if ( Groups_User_Group::read( $user_id, $group->group_id ) ) { 
?>

    Premium content here!

<?php } ?>
```

But this does not work on the subsite. Is there anyway I can check to see if the user is in a group on my main site FROM a subsite?

Comment: You will have to ask the author of the groups plugin about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with the following code:

```
<?php

    $blog_id = 1; //set the blog id to the main site id 

    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $group = Groups_Group::read_by_name( 'Premium' );
    if ( Groups_User_Group::read( $user_id, $group->group_id ) ) { 
        echo 'PREMIUM!!';
    } else {
        echo 'Not premium';
    }

    restore_current_blog();

?>
```